# Routing in C# based Web applications

Tags: c#, routes, web-frameworks

Not so much a general question as it is a "how would you approach it" so apologies if this doesn't belong on this particular stack. How ever I am curious as to how this is done in web frameworks built on .net.

Spring and ASP both have the concept of routing. in Rails we have a route file and thats handled by the web server after some hoops and jumps. In PHP we have the .htaccess file that states, this is where the index.php file lives, run everything off that.

But if one was to build a very bare bones, extremely basic C# web framework, how would they handle routing? Are there any examples of these type of simple (key word: simple) web frameworks out there that would allow me to poke around and understand a bit more about how such things like routing is handled?

**Update**

I should state I am not looking to understand how to use routing, but how, in C# based web frameworks, routing is implemented. is it XML files? is there a htaccess file?

hence my asking for a small web frameworks thats maybe being used for API so I could better understand, ok this is how you implement routing in a .net based web framework written in c#

Comment: Are you looking to see how to use it or how it works?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I am looking to understand how its implemented, so how it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is handler mapping section in IIS where you can specify handlers for a custom extension that you want to support. You can define you own HTTPHandlers and register them in IIS or web.config.

As far as Web API or MVC goes, framework provides the extensionless url handler. You can find their reference in the web.config file, which uses the Route mapping you provide during the application start to find the matching route for the URL. It uses various conventions to match the best action to the URL. Again you would custom define your convention or a configuration if you want to implement the handler yourself.

More info at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Because of how .net is going more open source and a lot of these frameworks will be developed on mac, linux and so on and even maybe run on linux will said frameworks make more use of the  extensionless url handler.

Answer (score 1):

Routing in asp.net is built into your code.  There are a couple ways you can define routes.  If you are going the API route, you can use the route attribute on your controllers and actions to define it or you can define them in a route config class.  The out of the box asp.net templates are a good starting point to see how they work.  Also read up on the MSDN site about routing here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: While useful I am not looking to get into the ASP side of things, more understand how said things could be implemented for applications not hosted on IIS servers ...  As .net and various Web frameworks become more open sourced I am looking to understand if the same concepts can be applied to say a linux server hosting a .net web application ... But i will deff check out your link - thanks.

Comment: if that is the case maybe you would want to look into OWIN: http://owin.org/

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess is an Apache concept so it does not really apply to C# web applications which generally run on IIS.

Routing in C# based web frameworks is handled in many different ways.  Some use XML, some don't.  The routing mechanism built into ASP.NET MVC uses naming conventions and optional attributes on the methods/controllers (Attribute routing).

If you were to implement your own routing, you could write an HTTP Module which checks incoming URLs and compares them to a given set of rewrite rules.  Those rewrite rules could be stored in an XML file, text file, database or really wherever you want.

Comment: Would these be handled differently due to the fact that in the future we might see C# based web frameworks and .net web applications running on say linux or mac servers (mostly linux) ??

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  This is just an implementation detail.  The only requirement needed to implement an URL rewriting module (which is essentially what routing is about) is to be able to hook into the web server's pipeline before the web application in question is processed. In IIS we have HTTP modules and HTTP handlers (ISAPI extensions as well), In Apache we have .htaccess and the RewriteEngine and so forth.